Question about using $\psi$ function to calculate $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(3 n+1)(3 n+2)(3 n+3)}$
Find the sum of the infinite series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(3 n+1)(3 n+2)(3 n+3)}$.I have trouble reading the answers to the exercises:

Because
$$
\frac{1}{(3 n+1)(3 n+2)(3 n+3)}=\frac{1}{6} \frac{1}{n+1 / 3}-\frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{n+2 / 3}+\frac{1}{6} \frac{1}{n+1}, \tag{1}
$$
Therefore, according to the summation formula given above, we have
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(3 n+1)(3 n+2)(3 n+3)}=-\frac{1}{6}\left[\psi\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)-2 \psi\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)+\psi(1)\right] .\tag{2} $$

I know that the $\psi$ function has the property that $\psi(z+n)=\psi(z)+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{z+n-1}, \quad n=2,3,4, \cdots$.
Now I only study the first part of $\frac{1}{6} \frac{1}{n+1 / 3}-\frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{n+2 / 3}+\frac{1}{6} \frac{1}{n+1}$, that is, $\frac{1}{n+1 / 3}$, and then I use the properties of the $\psi$ function to get: $\psi\left(\frac{1}{3}+n\right)=\psi\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{3}}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{3}}+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{3}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n-1+\frac{1}{3}}$,But this is not the addition of an infinite number of terms, but $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{3}}+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{3}}+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{3}}+\cdots$ is the addition of an infinite number of terms,Moreover, there is no $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}$ on the right side of equation (2). So how did the author get equation (2) from equation (1)?

After thinking for a while, here are my additional comments: I initially wanted to use $\psi(z+n)=\psi(z)+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{z+n-1}, \quad n=2,3,4, \cdots$. Because it contains a finite number of sums, there is a chance to take the limit of the sum to get the result. To save space, please read this first.Then the $a_k$ in the following discussion is consistent with the meaning of $a_k$ in Wikipedia, I will discuss it from another perspective: $\begin{aligned} \sum_{n=0}^N u_n & =\sum_{k=1}^m a_k\left[\psi\left(b_k+N\right)-\psi\left(b_k\right)\right]=\sum_{k=1}^m a_k\left[\psi\left(b_k+N\right)-\psi\left(b_k\right)\right]-\ln N \sum_{k=1}^m a_k \\ & =\sum_{k=1}^m a_k\left[\psi (b_k+N\right)-\ln N]-\sum_{k=1}^m a_k\psi\left(b_k\right) .\end{aligned}$, and then there is another property that $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}[\psi(z+n)-\ln n]=0$, so take the limit $N \rightarrow \infty$, and we get
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} u_n=\lim _{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^m a_k\left[\psi\left(b_k+N\right)-\ln N\right]-\sum_{k=1}^m a_k \psi\left(b_k\right)=-\sum_{k=1}^m a_k \psi\left(b_k\right) . $$

As itself, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+\frac13}$ diverges off to $\infty$. Compare with the harmonic series.

No, the individual summands of the form $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac1{n+s}$ diverge which is readily seen via comparison with the harmonic series. Instead we have that $$\begin{align} S &:= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{(3n+1)(3n+2)(3n+3)} 
\\ &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{6\left(n+\frac13\right)} - \frac{1}{6\left(n+\frac23\right)} - \frac{1}{6\left(n+\frac23\right)} + \frac{1}{6\left(n+1\right)} \\ 
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac16 \frac{\frac13}{\left(n+\frac13\right)\left(n+\frac23\right)} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac16 \frac{-\frac13}{(n+1)\left(n+\frac23\right)}\\
&= \frac1{18}\frac{\psi\left(\frac23\right) - \psi\left(\frac13\right)}{\frac23 - \frac13} - \frac{1}{18} \frac{\psi(1) - \psi\left(\frac23\right)}{1 - \frac23} \\
&= \frac16 \left(\psi\left(\frac23\right) - \psi\left(\frac13\right)\right) - \frac16\left(\psi(1)- \psi\left(\frac23\right)\right) \\
&= \frac16 \left(2\psi\left(\frac23\right) - \psi\left(\frac13\right) - \psi(1)\right) \\
&= \frac1{12}\left(\pi \sqrt 3 - 3\ln3\right)
\end{align}$$
Here I used the following facts: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{(n+a)(n+b)} = \frac{\psi(a) - \psi(b)}{a-b}$ where $a,b \notin \mathbb Z_{\le 0}$; $\psi(1) = -\gamma$; $\psi\left(\frac23\right) = -\gamma + \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt 3} - 3\frac{\ln(3)}2$; $\psi\left(\frac13\right) = -\gamma - \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt 3} - 3\frac{\ln 3}2$.
PS: This is my hundredth answer on Math.StackExchange!!! Probably not important for the reader, but a nice milestone to reach for myself.

Your answer is important to me too, I like the correct answer that carries some extra meaning.thanks
